# Div container going behind another one

Tags: css

If i resize the browser window c3 gets behind c2, I want c2 to be have a "barrier" so c3 does not go over/behind it. I've tried a lot of things with no success.

```
#c1 {

 float: middle;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 margin: auto;
}

#c2 {

 float: left;
 width: 100px;
 height: auto;
 margin: auto;
}

#c3 {

background-color: blue;
float: middle;
width: 500px;
height: 100px;
margin: auto;

}

<div id="c1">
<div id="c2">
a
b
c    
</div>
<div id="c3"></div>
```

Comment: You try z-index: 1 and position: relative ?

Comment: There is no such thing as 'float:middle'

Comment: yes, i already tried it

Comment: #c2 {

 float: left;
 width: 100px;
 height: auto;
 margin: auto;
clear: left;
}

Comment: It's missing a `</div>`.

Comment: @ David Addoteye does not work

Comment: you missed the closing dive for c1.

Answer (score 1):

Try floating them all left like so..

```
#c1 {

float: left;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
position: relative;
}

#c2 {

 float: left;
 width: 100px;
 height: auto;
 position: relative;
 }

#c3 {

background-color: blue;
float: left;
width: 500px;
height: 100px;
position: relative;

}

<div id="c1">
</div>
<div id="c2">
a
b
c    
</div>
<div id="c3"></div>
```

Comment: It creates a barrier but move c3 below c2, i would like side by side.

Comment: I edited the code to exclude the margins, try that and see how it works for you.

Comment: makes no difference :/

Comment: if you could send me a link where the code is live I can definitely make it work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Float:middle
```

isn't a real CSS property.

I'm not sure where you're putting your code but if things are overlapping it sounds like you'll want to use

```
position:relative
```

rather than

```
position:abolute
```

Try to add

```
position:relative !important
```

on those divs if you're using some sort of a CMS system.

Edit:  after reading your comments

```
Display: Inline
```

is what you're looking for

Comment: does not make difference, c3 goes below c2

Comment: when you say below you mean underneath?

Comment: yes, before the solutions presented here it was behind c2, now it is going underneath c2

Comment: what are the results you're trying to achieve?

Comment: i want c2 and c3 side by side, static, no matter the screen size. like tables

Comment: Display:inline is what you're looking for

Comment: a Div by default uses Display:block which will fill the whole line

Comment: still not working, i've been trying to move from tables to css but i think it is time to give up

Comment: display:inline will make it display like a book, starting at the left going to the right. Is this not doing that for you?